# Reaction to form amino acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, amino-acids

> $$\ce{CH2=CH-CH=O ->[CH3SH][(1,4 addition)] Product (P_1) ->[(i) NaCN][(ii) NH3\\(iii) H3O+] Q_1}$$
>
> Correct statement regarding $\ce{Q_1}?$
>
> 1. $\ce{Q_1}$ is essential amino acid
> 2. $\ce{Q_1}$ is acidic amino acid
> 3. $\ce{Q_1}$ is nonessential amino acid
> 4. $\ce{Q_1}$ on Lassign test gives prussian blue colour with $\ce{FeSO4}$ and $\ce{FeCl3}$ solution

By 1,4 addition (as mentioned in question) carbon-3 (taking carbon as carbon-1 of aldehyde group) will have $\ce{SCH3}$ added to it and oxygen must have $\ce{H}$ added to it.

After $\text{P}_1$ is formed, it can again tautomerize from an alcohol to an aldehyde.

The $\ce{^-CN}$ can now attack the aldehyde. Looking at the answer we can ay that the product must be an amino acid and so the $\ce{NH3}$ group and $\ce{^-CN}$ must be present on same carbon because then the $\ce{^-CN}$ will hydrolyze to give a $\ce{-COOH}$ group.

But how is $\ce{NH3}$ supposed to attack a carbon having $\ce{^-CN}$ and a hydroxyl group. Can we make the alcohol a leaving group somehow?

Or is the number of carbons in chain 1 less than what it should be? What should be the correct answer and approach for this problem?

Comment: Did you consider tautomerisation that could take place?

Comment: @safdar yes considered it after you mentioned and edited the question with a bit more attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The starting compound is an organic compound known as acrolein. $\ce{CH2=CH-CH=O}$

Now your first reaction would be:
$$\ce{CH2=CH-CH=O ->[CH3SH][1,4 addition]CH3-S-CH2-CH=CH-OH} $$

Now, this compound tautomerizes to form methional
$$\ce{CH3-S-CH2-CH=CH-OH <-> CH3-S-CH2-CH2-CH=O}$$

Now, the second step in your reaction is a named reaction known as [Strecker Amino Acid Synthesis](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2018/11/12/the-strecker-synthesis-of-amino-acids/). This converts an methional (in this case) into [methionine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methionine).
[image]

Now, onto the question at hand, it asks about certain properties of methionine. Methionine is an essential amino acid. So A is correct. Since methionine doesn't have any extra acid or base groups, it is neutral.

As for the [Lassaigne Test](http://www.olabs.edu.in/?sub=79&brch=7&sim=149&cnt=1), if the compound had only nitrogen, it would have shown a prussian blue color. However since there is sulphur as well, it shows a violet colouration. So, the answer is A.

Comment: However in strecker amino acid synthesis reaction they have added NH3 in first step and -CN in the next. And its given vice versa in the question. So will we still get the same product? Btw thank you for the explanation

Comment: Cyanide adds to the imine of the aldehyde. Ammonia doesn't displace hydroxyl in a cyanohydrin but ammonia will reverse the formation of the cyanohydrin.

Comment: @user55119 So can I sum this up as after we add cyanide Methional adds up the cyanide to it's aldehyde group , however upon addition of NH3 , some percentage of reaction goes back and then Streaker Amino Synthesis is followed.

Comment: No. The ammonia condenses with the thioaldehyde with loss of water to form an imine (Schiff's base). Then the cyanide adds to the imine.