# Which amino acids can be totally synthesized?

Tags: biochemistry, synthesis, reference-request, proteins, amino-acids

I can't find information regarding which amino acids (say the proteinogenic ones or in general) can be totally synthesized. Is there a reference?

Comment: Synthesized in the body? Synthesized chemically? Which one?

Comment: Also, amino acid is a general concept such as $\alpha,$ $\beta,$ etc. Thus question can be categorized as too broad.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne proteinogenic amino acids are all $\alpha$

Comment: Glycine can be synthesized from acetic acid. First acetic acid can be chlorinated by reacting with chlorine gas. Then the chloracetic acid reacts with ammonium carbonate. This produces ammonium chloracetate, that can be transformed into amino acetic acid (glycine). See the details the procedure in typing Gycine Synthesis in Google.

Comment: An [example of a possible synthesis of methionine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136781/reaction-to-form-amino-acid/136785#136785). Seems too broad

Comment: All of them can be accessed synthetically